# python "multiple" combine/chain list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools, function-composition

I am quite new to python and I have been learning list comprehension alongside python lists and dictionaries.

So, I would like to do something like:

```
[my_functiona(x) for x in a]
```

..which works completely fine.

However, now I'd want to do the following:

```
[my_functiona(x) for x in a] && [my_functionb(x) for x in a]
```

..is there a way to combine or chain such list comprehension? - where the second function uses the result of the first list. SHortly speaking, I would like to apply `my_functiona` and  `my_functionb` sequentuially to list `a`

I did try googling this - but could not find anything satisfactory.
Sorry if this is a stupid 101 question!

Comment: **Note:** as of 2022-02-23 none of the answers on this post use "chaining" of list comprehension in the sense of the word as described in this link https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/arsu8/chaining_vs_nesting/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just iterate over the result of the first comprehension:

```
def double(x):
    return x*2
def inc(x):
    return x+1

[double(x) for x in (inc(y) for y in range(10))]
```

I made the inner comprehension a generator expression as you don't need to get the full list.

Answer (score 6):

You can compose the functions like this

```
[my_functionb(my_functiona(x)) for x in a]
```

The form in Thomas' answer is useful if you need to apply a condition

```
[my_functionb(y) for y in (my_functiona(x) for x in a) if y<10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[my_functiona(my_functionb(x)) for x in a]
```